# JDBC Query doesn't return any result but the same query works on the database shell

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have huge problem unable to figure out the issue, highly appreciate help with thanks in advance.

```
        con = getConnection(SFPQueries.DATASOURCE);         
        stmt1 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT A.SUMMARIZATION_QUERY, A.AGGREGATE_ID, B.TOKEN, C.FACT_TOKEN, D.FIELD_ID, D.MEASURES "+
                "FROM SUMMARIZATION_TIME_AGGRREGATE_MAPPING_TB A, SUMMARIZATION_TB B, FACT_TB C, SUMMARIZATION_MEASURES_MAPPING_TB D "+
                "WHERE A.SUMMARIZATION_ID=B.SUMMARIZATION_ID AND B.FACT_ID=C.FACT_ID AND A.SUMMARIZATION_ID=D.SUMMARIZATION_ID AND A.AGGREGATE_ID=?");
        stmt1.setInt(1,1);
        rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery();
        if(_log.isDebugEnabled()){_log.debug(" >> BEFORE " + rs1.next());}
```

**For the above JDBC query there are always no result returned by JDBC.**

10/04/2014 11:41:56.866 INFO  com.hp.sfp.core.dao.impl.BaseDAO : enter getConnection()
10/04/2014 11:41:57.253 INFO  com.hp.sfp.core.dao.impl.BaseDAO : Database information: Url=jdbc:vertica://*****/ABCD username=xyz password=xyz@123
10/04/2014 11:41:57.254 INFO  com.hp.sfp.core.dao.impl.BaseDAO : Exit getConnection()
10/04/2014 11:41:57.382 DEBUG com.hp.sfp.core.dao.impl.SummarizationJobDAOImpl :  >> BEFORE false

**But when I use the same query on shell I get the result!**

```
=> SELECT DISTINCT A.SUMMARIZATION_QUERY, A.AGGREGATE_ID, B.TOKEN, C.FACT_TOKEN,    D.FIELD_ID, D.MEASURES FROM SUMMARIZATION_TIME_AGGRREGATE_MAPPING_TB A, SUMMARIZATION_TB B, FACT_TB C, SUMMARIZATION_MEASURES_MAPPING_TB D WHERE A.SUMMARIZATION_ID=B.SUMMARIZATION_ID AND B.FACT_ID=C.FACT_ID AND A.SUMMARIZATION_ID=D.SUMMARIZATION_ID AND A.AGGREGATE_ID=1;
SUMMARIZATION_QUERY | AGGREGATE_ID |       TOKEN        | FACT_TOKEN | FIELD_ID |        MEASURES
---------------------+--------------+--------------------+------------+----------+---------
select * from ...   |            1 | summary_for_charge | chargefact |       37 |    CALL_END_CAUSE
select * from ...   |            1 | summary_for_charge | chargefact |        1 | STRUCTURE_CODE
select * from ...   |            1 | summary_for_charge | chargefact |       45 | ROAMER_INDICATOR
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure your Java program connects to the same database?

Comment: I have copied the detail from the log file, Database URL seems to be correct. Also when I change the SQL query the situation remains the same. Could it be that the table is corrupt?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, someone explain me that I didn't run 'COMMIT'. So on the database shell it shows the result where as through JDBC I can't. This was the issue.